# How do I unmarshal a dynamic type from JSON with Spring RestTemplate and Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON response coming from an API that is calling Elastic Search. The following is a sample snippet.

```
{
  "fielda" : "something",
  "hits" : {
    "total" : "100",
    "type" : "/some/type"
    "dynamicAttributes":{
       "somevalue1" : "somevalue",
       "somevalue2" : "somevalue2"
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON subtree underneath the `dynamicAttributes` can be different with each result. I am trying to marshal that into an object based on the `type` field that comes in. There will be an established mapping between that value and a class somewhere in a map. It looks like Jackson maps the results into a `LinkedHashMap` if the type is not resolved. I'm looking to use a Custom Deserializer. Is this the best strategy for this? Or is there something simpler that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubType` annotations to marshal the given input.

On your dynamicAttributes field you can add a JsonTypeInfo annotation to specify how to create a dynamicAttribute's object. The `EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` type conveys that the `type` field is present at the level of `dynamicAttributes`.

```
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property ="type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
      visible = true)
  DynamicAttributes dynamicAttributes;
```

To specify the possible subtypes use the `JsonSubTypes` annotation as shown below

```
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DynamicAttributesType1.class, name = "type1")
  , @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DynamicAttributesType2.class, name = "type2")
})
public abstract class DynamicAttributes{
}
```

Comment: @JCB did it solve your issue ? Please feel free to modify the answer if something was not complete.